# How can I force the command line to run a program from the lower-most folder where the file is located?

Tags: command-line, scripting

I am trying to write a script to run a small c++ program on another, higher-end computing environment. I have the script working on my local PC but I want to write the command as a .bat file so I can give it to someone else to run. The issue that I am running in to is that the file is set to run on my local PC and therefore it follows my directory path. I want it to be able to run from a single file, regardless of the entire directory path.

```
cd C:\Users\username\Desktop\file\subfile1\subfile2
```

This change the working directory to the file on my desktop where the c++ program and file are located.

```
main -m C:\Users\username\Desktop\file\subfile1\subfile2\c++_file_part1 C:\Users\username\Desktop\file\subfile1\subfile2\c++_file_part2 > C:\Users\username\Desktop\file\subfile1\subfile2\output.txt
```

The purpose of the above code is to run the c++ program (consists of 2 parts), but it runs it from the subfile2 location on my desktop, which is located in subfile1, file, ...etc. Is there a way where I can give someone a file named 'subfile2' and they will be able to run in on their computer, or I can take the file to another computer via flash drive?

The entire purpose of this program is to transcribe audio using 5 different formats. Each format has a different latency and processing speed, so I am trying to figure out if the transcription time will be different by having the program run as a script to make it easier rather than run it manually.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not familar with this operation (using `main -m`) but are you saying that code works? Assuming yes, then the simplest thing to try is to make a dir on your thumb drive and copy code and data to that dir, may `F:\myTest`. a bat file should then just be a transcription of what you type on the cmdline to get the output. You only need to  cd into `myTest` (from the F: drive) and execute `./part1 > file ; ./part2 >>file`. Otherwise you need to read a bit more about how `.bat` files work and (possibly) be more clear (to us) about how your system is producing output now. Good luck.

Comment: Oh, it the `main -m` thing. Not sure how you get the mechanism to a thumb drive. Above imay work so give it a quick test (on mutilple machines (-;). Good luck.